# Выпадающее меню hover в Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, hover, dropdown

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши выпадало меню 'ul', но данный код не работает.

```css
.nav .dp-style > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.nav .dp-style > ul {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 180px;
  background: #B5B5B5;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nav .dp-style > a:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown dp-style">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Test Page</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">League</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Leaders' cup</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Country cups</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dp-style > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.dp-style > ul {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 180px;
  background: #B5B5B5;
}
.dp-style>.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.dp-style:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bzwu35e9/

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте последний селектор на такой:

```css
.nav .dp-style > a:hover+ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Вы указали ul как дочерний, а он - сосед.

Comment: к сожалению, это ничего не меняет. меню все также выпадает только после клика

Comment: потому что у вас в куске кода вначале ещё везде стоит .nav , а если смотреть по текущем html - то его тут нет. удалите тоже

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dp-style > ul{
float: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
min-width: 180px;
background: #B5B5B5;
display: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dp-style>a:hover {
background: transparent;
color: red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dp-style:hover ul{
display: block;
```